# Binary search in python 3.6

Tags: python, binary

I am writing a binary search function for a school assignment and while it works fine for my own tests, checking it in the upload submission portal returns that it fails the majority of hidden tests. Is there anything obviously wrong with it, i.e the assignment for left, right, middle being incorrect etc? (other than it being very crude)

EDIT: added more details that were missing, yes the list in stolen_plates will be sorted.
The test I have at the bottom works fine for me but there must be something I am overlooking for it to fail the submission tests

```
def binary_simple_plate_finder(stolen_plates, sighted_plates):

    result_list = []
    
    total_comparisons = 0
    for plate in sighted_plates:
        middle = (len(stolen_plates) - 1) // 2
        right = (len(stolen_plates) - 1)
        left = 0
        finished = False
        while not finished:
            if plate == stolen_plates[middle]:
                total_comparisons = total_comparisons + 1
                result_list.append(plate)
                finished = True
            elif left == right and plate != stolen_plates[middle]:
                total_comparisons = total_comparisons + 1
                finished = True            
            elif plate > stolen_plates[middle]:
                total_comparisons = total_comparisons + 1
                left = middle + 1
                middle = ((left + right) // 2)
            elif plate < stolen_plates[middle]:
                total_comparisons = total_comparisons + 1
                right = middle - 1
                middle = ((left + right) // 2)
            
    return result_list, total_comparisons

stolen = ["ABJ603", "BADMON", "CHUD69", "CRAP22", "DENGEL", "EFFETE", "IMGAY", "NINGAS", "OKEDOK", "PUS556", "ZMAN21"]
sighted = ["OKEDOK", "ABJ603", "BASTAR", "NINGAS"]
print(binary_simple_plate_finder(stolen, sighted))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some description and/or examples of usage for this function. I can't understand what you are looking for with this binary search function. Which algorithm are you trying to implement?

Comment: provide complete code.

Comment: @Mehmaam If the code does not do what you need how can I use it to understand where's your problem?

Comment: sighted_plates, stolen_plates, where is input data? may be he input data which can fulfill his requirement but not other requirements.

Comment: Are you sure that `stolen_plates` is sorted?  That's a requirement for any binary search, but I don't see an explicit `sort` here.

Comment: I notice that you only increment `total_comparisons` for comparisons that complete, not those that fail.  Maybe that's the component that's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a binary search implementation that also counts the number of comparisons.

```
def bsearch(lst, x):
    c = 0
    L = 0
    R = len(lst) - 1
    while L <= R:
        m = (L + R) // 2
        c += 1
        if (v := lst[m]) == x:
            return m, c
        c += 1
        if v < x:
            L = m + 1
        else:
            R = m - 1
    return -1, c

stolen_plates = sorted(["ABJ603", "BADMON", "CHUD69", "CRAP22", "DENGEL", "EFFETE", "IMGAY", "NINGAS", "OKEDOK", "PUS556", "ZMAN21"])

sighted_plates = ["OKEDOK", "ABJ603", "BASTAR", "NINGAS"]

result_list = [] # list of stolen plates that have been sighted

total_comparisons = 0

for plate in sighted_plates:
    i, c = bsearch(stolen_plates, plate)
    if i >= 0:
        result_list.append(plate)
    total_comparisons += c

print(*result_list, sep='\n')
print(f'{total_comparisons=}')
```

**Output:**

```
OKEDOK
ABJ603
NINGAS
total_comparisons=23
```